# Conditional operator in Mako using Pylons

Tags: php, python, pylons, conditional-operator, mako

In PHP, I often use the conditional operator to add an attribute to an html element if it applies to the element in question. For example:

```
<select name="blah">
    <option value="1"<?= $blah == 1 ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ?>>
        One
    </option>
    <option value="2"<?= $blah == 2 ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ?>>
        Two
    </option>
</select>
```

I'm starting a project with Pylons using Mako for the templating. How can I achieve something similar? Right now, I see two possibilities that are not ideal.

Solution 1:

```
<select name="blah">
    % if blah == 1:
    <option value="1" selected="selected">One</option>
    % else:
    <option value="1">One</option>
    % endif
    % if blah == 2:
    <option value="2" selected="selected">Two</option>
    % else:
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    % endif
</select>
```

Solution 2:

```
<select name="blah">
    <option value="1"
    % if blah == 1:
        selected="selected"
    % endif
    >One</option>
    <option value="2"
    % if blah == 2:
        selected="selected"
    % endif
    >Two</option>
</select>
```

In this particular case, the value is equal to the variable tested (value="1" => blah == 1), but I use the same pattern in other situations, like `<?= isset($variable) ? ' value="$variable" : '' ?>`.

I am looking for a clean way to achieve this using Mako.

Comment: Just so you're aware, `? :` is *a* ternary operator. It happens to be the only one so it often gets misnomered as *the* ternary operator. It's real name is the "conditional operator".

Comment: You're right, I also corrected the title of the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it's running Python, the "ternary operator" is

```
# condition ? trueValue : falseValue
trueValue if condition else falseValue
```

Comment: Yes, thanks!
${' selected="selected"' if blah == 1 | n} works great.
${' selected="selected"' if blah == 1 else ' something-else' | n} also works great.

Comment: I tried your suggested solution ${' selected="selected"' if customer['content']['status'] == 1 | n}  but I keep getting a SyntaxError saying invalid syntax.  It prints something along the lines of:  (u'str(\'selected="selected"\') if customer["content"][')